# How to handle/highlight/mark multiple brackets (),{},[], and «» in regular expression using regex101 PHP

Tags: php

I want to mark multiple brackets (),{},[], and «» using regular expression in regex101 tool currently i am handling () this bracket i am unable to other brackets.

```
(?|([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\(([a-zA-Z\s]+)\)|\(([a-zA-Z\s]+)\)([a-zA-Z0-9]+))
```

[regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/9PCacf/5)

Comment: Added the regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right you can use next regex:

```
/(\b[\(|\{|\[|\«]+[\w\s]*[\)|\}|\]|\»]+)/g
```

And link on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Si4smS/1)

---

**UDP1:** Updated link on regex101

---

**UPD2:** Updated regex looks like

```
/(\b[\(|\{|\[|\«]+[\w\s]*[\)|\}|\]|\»]+)|(\B[\(|\{|\[|\«]+.*[\)|\}|\]|\»]+\b)/g
```

[link](https://regex101.com/r/Si4smS/3)

Comment: but problem here when i match from start i does not match example.
https://regex101.com/r/9PCacf/7

Comment: in above updated link i does not highlight this word 
[weathe]r is fine 
{weather is fin}e 
{weathe}r is fine  
«weather  is fi»ne  etc in example

Comment: update regex it does not handle  [weathe]r is fine {weather is fin}e {weathe}r is fine «weather is fi»ne words please help this

https://regex101.com/r/9PCacf/7

Comment: Please also guide this in single brackets [,{,(,«

https://regex101.com/r/9PCacf/13